# Zombie process (How to exit game properly with JFrame?)

Tags: java, jframe

I currently have the following code:

```
package Joehot200;

//Import pure java junk here - No libraries.

public class Main extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */ 
static Main frame = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setTitle("Privateers");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Main() {
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    final JButton btnEnterBattlefield =  new JButton("Enter battlefield!"); 
    btnEnterBattlefield.setForeground(Color.red);
    //btnEnterBattlefield.setBackground(Color.green);
    //btnEnterBattlefield.setOpaque(true);
    menuBar.add(btnEnterBattlefield);
    btnEnterBattlefield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

           //For the sake of this code example, this does nothing as the error happens even if I do not click the button.
        } 
    });      

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);


}
```

Is for some reason leaving a zombie process. I have got no idea why.

I will point out that this is before I have pressed any buttons on the start screen. However, if it has not yet got to the start screen then the zombie process does not yet occur.

So, how can I exit my game properly?

Comment: If I were you I would test for an exception. It most likely is being handled, but is not outputting any text or sign. Exceptions tend to be what cause such horrendous CPU exhaustion.

Comment: Should TerrainDemo.startGame() not be on the line after frame.setTitle("Privateers"); ? Right now you don't know if frame have been initialized when calling TerrainDemo.startGame

Comment: Edited code to be a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Still got this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I should post this in a comment, not as an answer but I have no enought reputation.
Your code is OK, may be the process you are seeing is from your IDE?

This is my java processes before I run your code: 
    
    `[victor@aluminio:~/Help/src]$ps -Al | grep java
    0 S   118  2651     1  0  80   0 - 169381 ?     ?        00:00:24 java
    0 S  1000  8151  8148  6  80   0 - 807368 -     ?        00:06:18 java
    0 S  1000  9047  9028 15  80   0 - 437349 -     pts/1    00:07:43 java`

Then I run the code, that creates the 10217 process:
    
    `[victor@aluminio:~/Help/src]$java Main &
    [1] 10217
    [victor@aluminio:~/Help/src]$ps -Al | grep java
    0 S   118  2651     1  0  80   0 - 169381 ?     ?        00:00:24 java
    0 S  1000  8151  8148  6  80   0 - 807368 -     ?        00:06:19 java
    0 S  1000  9047  9028 15  80   0 - 437349 -     pts/1    00:07:43 java
    0 S  1000 10217  7232  5  80   0 - 498657 -     pts/0    00:00:00 java`

Then I close the window, and run this check:
    
    `[victor@aluminio:~/Help/src]$ps -Al | grep java
    0 S   118  2651     1  0  80   0 - 169381 ?     ?        00:00:24 java
    0 S  1000  8151  8148  6  80   0 - 807368 -     ?        00:06:21 java
    0 S  1000  9047  9028 14  80   0 - 437349 -     pts/1    00:07:44 java
    [1]+  Done                    java Main
    [victor@aluminio:~/Help/src]$`

The process finished as expected.